# Arduino & CC3000 & Motorshield & Robot

Tags: rest, arduino

I have a 4 Motor Drive car that has  ARD MEGA / CC3000 / Motorshield on it.
I have written a sketch that runs REST and a webpage with buttons, which works fine in Serial.
I have written a sketch that controls the Motors Forwards / Backwards / Left  / Right and this works fine.
When I combine the 2 Sketches and press FORWARD on the webpage it works but then 'Hangs'.

```
    void loop()
    {
      // Handle any multicast DNS requests
      mdns.update();
      Adafruit_CC3000_ClientRef client = restServer.available();
      rest.handle(client);
      wdt_reset();
      if(!cc3000.checkConnected()){while(1){}}
      wdt_reset(); 
    }

    int forward(String command) {
      goforwards();
      return 1;
    }
    int backward(String command) {

      gobackwards();
      return 1;
    }
    int left(String command) {
      Serial.println(F("GO LEFT..."));
      //goleft();
      return 1;
    }
    int right(String command) {
      Serial.println(F("GO RIGHT..."));
      //goright();
      return 1;
    }
    int estop(String command) {
      Serial.println(F("Asked to STOP..."));
       allstop();
       return 1;
    }

    void goforwards() {
     Serial.println(F("GO FORWARD..."));
      motor(1, FORWARD, 150); motor(4, FORWARD, 150);  motor(2, FORWARD, 150); motor(3, FORWARD, 150);  delay(500); 
      allstop();
    }
    void gobackwards() {
     Serial.println(F("GO BACKWARD..."));
     motor(1, BACKWARD, 150); motor(4, BACKWARD, 150);  motor(2, BACKWARD, 150); motor(3, BACKWARD, 150);  delay(500); 
     allstop();
    }
    void goleft() {motor(1, FORWARD, 175); motor(4, FORWARD, 175); motor(2, FORWARD, 50); motor(3, FORWARD, 50);delay(2000); }
    void goright() {motor(1, FORWARD, 50); motor(4, FORWARD, 50); motor(2, FORWARD, 175); motor(3, FORWARD, 175); delay(2000); }
    void allstop() {motor(1, RELEASE, 0); motor(2, RELEASE, 0);motor(3, RELEASE, 0);motor(4, RELEASE, 0);delay(1); }

    void motor(int nMotor, int command, int speed)
    {
      int motorA, motorB;

      if (nMotor >= 1 && nMotor <= 4)
      {  
        switch (nMotor)
        {
        case 1:
          motorA   = MOTOR1_A;
          motorB   = MOTOR1_B;
          break;
        case 2:
          motorA   = MOTOR2_A;
          motorB   = MOTOR2_B;
          break;
        case 3:
          motorA   = MOTOR3_A;
          motorB   = MOTOR3_B;
          break;
        case 4:
          motorA   = MOTOR4_A;
          motorB   = MOTOR4_B;
          break;
        default:
          break;
        }

        switch (command)
        {
        case FORWARD:
          motor_output (motorA, HIGH, speed);
          motor_output (motorB, LOW, -1);     // -1: no PWM set
          break;
        case BACKWARD:
          motor_output (motorA, LOW, speed);
          motor_output (motorB, HIGH, -1);    // -1: no PWM set
          break;
        case BRAKE:
          motor_output (motorA, LOW, 255); // 255: fully on.
          motor_output (motorB, LOW, -1);  // -1: no PWM set
          break;
        case RELEASE:
          motor_output (motorA, LOW, 0);  // 0: output floating.
          motor_output (motorB, LOW, -1); // -1: no PWM set
          break;
        default:
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    void motor_output (int output, int high_low, int speed)
    {
      int motorPWM;

      switch (output)
      {
      case MOTOR1_A:
      case MOTOR1_B:
        motorPWM = MOTOR1_PWM;
        break;
      case MOTOR2_A:
      case MOTOR2_B:
        motorPWM = MOTOR2_PWM;
        break;
      case MOTOR3_A:
      case MOTOR3_B:
        motorPWM = MOTOR3_PWM;
        break;
      case MOTOR4_A:
      case MOTOR4_B:
        motorPWM = MOTOR4_PWM;
        break;
      default:
        // Use speed as error flag, -3333 = invalid output.
        speed = -3333;
        break;
      }

      if (speed != -3333)
      {
        shiftWrite(output, high_low);

       if (speed >= 0 && speed <= 255)    
        {
          analogWrite(motorPWM, speed);
        }
      }
    }

    void shiftWrite(int output, int high_low)
    {
      static int latch_copy;
      static int shift_register_initialized = false;


      if (!shift_register_initialized)
      {
        pinMode(MOTORLATCH, OUTPUT);
        pinMode(MOTORENABLE, OUTPUT);
        pinMode(MOTORDATA, OUTPUT);
        pinMode(MOTORCLK, OUTPUT);

        // Set pins for shift register to default value (low);
        digitalWrite(MOTORDATA, LOW);
        digitalWrite(MOTORLATCH, LOW);
        digitalWrite(MOTORCLK, LOW);
        // Enable the shift register, set Enable pin Low.
        digitalWrite(MOTORENABLE, LOW);

        // start with all outputs (of the shift register) low
        latch_copy = 0;

        shift_register_initialized = true;
      }

      // The defines HIGH and LOW are 1 and 0.
      // So this is valid.
      bitWrite(latch_copy, output, high_low);

      // Use the default Arduino 'shiftOut()' function to
      // shift the bits with the MOTORCLK as clock pulse.
      // The 74HC595 shiftregister wants the MSB first.
      // After that, generate a latch pulse with MOTORLATCH.
      shiftOut(MOTORDATA, MOTORCLK, MSBFIRST, latch_copy);
      delayMicroseconds(5);    // For safety, not really needed.
      digitalWrite(MOTORLATCH, HIGH);
      delayMicroseconds(5);    // For safety, not really needed.
      digitalWrite(MOTORLATCH, LOW);
    }
```

The code above is the Meat where something is going wrong. The code above this is all fine.
WHen the code gets the command 'forward' it runs the VOID goforwards(); but then 'hangs'. Same for 'backwards'.
Seems to get stuck in these VOIDS and so does not respond to the next command from webpage.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'd suggest you to 1) format the code better, particularly the indentation (otherwise it's almost impossible to read it clearly) 2) to dtect what is the point where it hangs. In order to do it, you can add some `Serial.println`s to the code and check where it hangs.